# Can this calculus question be proved by linear algebra? A proof by Intermediate Theorem if possible is also expected.

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, roots

Question:

Let $a_0+\frac {a_1} {2}+...+\frac {a_n} {n+1}=0$, prove that there exists at least one point $\xi$ that $$\psi(x)=a_0+a_1x+...+a_nx^n=0 (0<x<1).$$

I already proved it by Rolle's Theorem by integrating $\psi(x)$.

I was wondering if this question can be proved by linear algebra. Because it looks so much like finding the solution of equation

$$ \bigg\{ a_0y_0+a_1y_1+...+a_ny_n=0 $$

One solution of it is

$$\vec {y_1}=(1, 1/2,..., 1/(n+1)),$$

then prove another solution exists and can be a geometric sequence

$\{x^n\}$ and ${x^n} < 1 (n=0, 1, 2,...)$.